# Autohotkey to paste multiple email blurbs

Tags: autohotkey

I am using autohot keys to send the email blurbs (with multiple sentences) using unique text command with SendInput. However it is sending the instruction word by word and taking a lot of time to send all the text in blurb.

I want know is there any clipboard tool available in AHK where i can store multiple blurbs (each blurb contains more than 3 rows of sentences) and paste the blurbs by pressing unique text command associated to each blurb. It should work similar to the Magical - Text Expander & Autofill extension in chrome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See [Clipboard](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm). If you have trouble coding it, you can come back here and show your code.